# Solution for error in registerreceiver

Tags: java, android, android-service

i am using the following code to register a receiver but it shows me an error saying
Syntax error or tokens,misplaced constructor
Here is the code for
Also i want this to run even when the app is closed

## MyService.java

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    if (!registered) {
        MyReceiver mybroadcast = new MyReceiver(){
        registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
        registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
    }    
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: I think you have a missing brace like @octopus says

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        if (!registered) {

            MyBroadcast mybroadcast=new MyBroadcast();

            registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
            registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));

    }
}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private class MyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                     //TODO some code here
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: yes missing braces in one problem another one is registerReceiver need two argument one broadcast receiver second intent filter in that case broadcast receiver parameter is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define you receiver first , than register it :

```
BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver (){
@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//define what you want the receiver to do when it is called
    }    


};
```

then register it :

```
registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
```

in your case you want to put two IntentFilter ,so do this :

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction((Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
intentFilter.addAction((Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
registerReceiver(mybroadcast, intentFilter);
```

You will get new exceptions or warnings if you don't unregister the receiver, and in the same time you want that the service keep working, so unregister the receiver in onDestroy :

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Service#onDestroy()
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);        
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate()` method misses closing brace `}`. Formatting helps you fix these kind of errors. You haven't shown us fully what you have done. Please follow this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) to understand

Comment: Did you define your receiver?